# Problem is installation with Scilab 5.4.0

Tags: 12.04, scilab

After installation whenever i am trying to run scilab, i m getting the following message.
Please help.

```
scilab-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The current version of scilab in 12.04 is 5.3.3. How did you install the 5.4.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

A few notes I gathered from info found over the internet to quickly get you started:

(1)  Make sure Scilab is installed in /home/youruserID to ensure that you can change ./bin/scilab into an executable.  If it is an NFTS system, it can not be changed into an executable.

(2)  Get updates for Ubuntu.
Open up a terminal, or Xterm:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

(3)  Problem with installing Scilab: missing libXss.so.1
You need to install libxsss1.

Again under Xterm:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

(4) To launch Scilab in Xterm:

```
cd <scilab-path>/scilab-5.4.1
./bin/scilab
```

(5) To create shortcut on Desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```